# Jupyter Notebook & colab: Fonts not set to monospace

Tags: fonts, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, google-colaboratory, monospace

When setting custom fonts in Jupyter Lab via the settings menu, it does change the font in code cells - but it is not rendered out as monospaced anymore.

[image: codeCellConfig in Jupyter Lab]

This makes the code itself a lot less readable in comparison to monospaced fonts:

[image: Non-monospaced in JupyterLab]

The font of choice here is meant to be monospaced. So, I'm stuck here, can't figure out why it's not rendered out like this.

I do encounter the same issue in google colab. There, the font is set via
chrome://settings/fonts
-fixed size font

There again, i can change the font itself, but no matter the font of choice, it is rendered out as non-monospaced.

Is this a common issue? Can anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this problem gets solved by restarting not JupyterLab or colab or the browser, but the computer itself.

I'm running Win10, at the next startup it miraculously displayed the font with the correct spacing.